# relative rotation in 3D

Tags: python, angle

I have an object (XYZ-coordinate system where Z is up) that rotates from t0 to t1 with the corresponding rotation matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
r_0 = np.array([[-0.02659679, -0.00281247,  0.99964229],
                [ 0.76308514, -0.64603356,  0.01848528],
                [ 0.64575048,  0.76330382,  0.01932857]])

r_1 = np.array([[ 0.05114056, -0.03815443,  0.99796237],
               [-0.30594799,  0.95062582,  0.05202294],
               [-0.95067369, -0.30798506,  0.03694226]])

# Calculate the relative rotation matrix from t0 to t1
rot_mat_rel = np.matmul(np.transpose(r_0), r_1)
r = R.from_maxtrix(rot_mat_rel)
# Obtain angles
print(r.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)

# Result
array([  -1.52028392,   -1.55242217, -148.10677483])
```

The problem is, that the relative angles look wrong to me but I can't find my mistake. What I wanted to know is how much the object rotated along x, y and z.

Edit: Code to for plots: https://codeshare.io/GA9zK8

Comment: Is your `r_0` and `r_1` the same as `rot_mat_0` and `rot_mat_1` respectively?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: `np.degrees(r.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)` doesn't look right.  If you can get `as_euler()` to return values in degrees, you shouldn't need to then convert the result to degrees!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `matrix_from_euler_xyz` from [this tutorial](https://dfki-ric.github.io/pytransform3d/rotations.html) to check your results.

(You might need to run `pip3 install pytransform3d` in your terminal where you are running your python code from, or `!pip3 install pytransform3d` from Jupyter Notebook if you are using that.)

Preparing the data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
r_0 = np.array([[-0.02659679, -0.00281247,  0.99964229],
                [ 0.76308514, -0.64603356,  0.01848528],
                [ 0.64575048,  0.76330382,  0.01932857]])

r_1 = np.array([[ 0.05114056, -0.03815443,  0.99796237],
                [-0.30594799,  0.95062582,  0.05202294],
                [-0.95067369, -0.30798506,  0.03694226]])

# Calculate the relative rotation matrix from t0 to t1
rot_mat_rel = np.matmul(np.transpose(r_0), r_1)
r = R.from_matrix(rot_mat_rel)
```

Let's plot what the rotation `r` means in practice:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from pytransform3d.rotations import *

ax = plot_basis(R=np.eye(3), ax_s=1)

p = np.array([0, 0, 0])

R = matrix_from_euler_xyz(r.as_euler('xyz'))
plot_basis(ax, R, p, alpha = 0.5)

plt.show()
```

We obtain this plot:

[image]

You can check if this is what you expected or not.

Check the rotation matrix which the `pytransform3d` module calculated from Euler angles `r`:

```
matrix_from_euler_xyz(r.as_euler('xyz'))
```

Giving ouput:

```
array([[-0.84872253, -0.52814402,  0.02709157],
       [ 0.52754172, -0.84911505, -0.02652111],
       [ 0.03701082, -0.00821713,  0.99928108]])
```

which is exactly the traspose of `np.matmul(np.transpose(r_0), r_1)`:

```
array([[-0.84872253,  0.52754172,  0.03701082],
       [-0.52814402, -0.84911505, -0.00821714],
       [ 0.02709157, -0.02652111,  0.99928109]])
```

Which seems a good sign & may be a good starting point for checking your math.

As I don't see what you would expect to get, I suggest you experiment with plotting your results with the tools outlined here, and check step by step that what you have is what you have expected to have.

Comment: Thanks for introducing pytransform3d. I was wondering if it is possible to use a list of X,Y,Z coordinates as an input to transform. According to the manual, it works only with axes.

Comment: I added the plots corresponding to the rotation matrices.

Comment: Could you include the code as well with which you produced the plots? :)

Comment: I had to outsource the code due to the character limits, here is the link: https://codeshare.io/GA9zK8

Comment: I still couldn't identify where the mistake is. Visually, the angle change should be around 30 degrees in z but not -148 degrees.

Comment: Created a room to discuss the issue: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218527/pythonic-rotations

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably a bit late and zabop's answer already points to the right direction. I just want to clarify two things.

There are several ambiguities when we work with transformations that can make things more confusing. The two things that might make the code here a bit confusing are:

- [active vs. passive rotation](https://dfki-ric.github.io/pytransform3d/transformation_ambiguities.html#active-alibi-vs-passive-alias-transformation)
- [intrinsic vs. extrinsic rotation](https://dfki-ric.github.io/pytransform3d/transformation_ambiguities.html#intrinsic-vs-extrinsic-transformations)

I'm starting from your example above:

```py
import numpy as np
r_0 = np.array([[-0.02659679, -0.00281247,  0.99964229],
                [ 0.76308514, -0.64603356,  0.01848528],
                [ 0.64575048,  0.76330382,  0.01932857]])
r_1 = np.array([[ 0.05114056, -0.03815443,  0.99796237],
                [-0.30594799,  0.95062582,  0.05202294],
                [-0.95067369, -0.30798506,  0.03694226]])
```

The way I would calculate a rotation matrix that rotates `r_0` to `r_1` is the following (different from your code!):

```py
r0_to_r1 = r_1.dot(r_0.T)
r0_to_r1
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0.99635252,  0.08212126,  0.0231898 ],
       [ 0.05746796, -0.84663889,  0.52905579],
       [ 0.06308011, -0.52579339, -0.84827012]])
```

I use the extrinsic convention for concatenation of rotation matrices, that is, `r_1` is applied after `r_0.T`. (If `r_0` and `r_1` were real numbers, we would write `r_1 - r_0` to obtain a number that transforms `r_0` to `r_1`.)

You can verify that `r0_to_r1` rotates from `r_0` to `r_1`:

```py
from numpy.testing import assert_array_almost_equal
# verify correctness: apply r0_to_r1 after r_0
assert_array_almost_equal(r_1, r0_to_r1.dot(r_0))
# would raise an error if test fails
```

Anyway, the intrinsic convention would also work:

```py
r0_to_r1_intrinsic = r_0.T.dot(r_1)
assert_array_almost_equal(r_1, r_0.dot(r0_to_r1_intrinsic))
```

Since zabop introduced pytransform3d, I would also like to clarify that scipy uses **active** rotation matrices and the rotation matrix that `pytransform3d.rotations.euler_xyz_from_matrix` produces is a **passive** rotation matrix! This wasn't documented so clearly in previous versions. You can transform an active rotation matrix to a passive rotation matrix and vice versa with the matrix transpose. Both pytransform3d's function and scipy's `Rotation.to_euler("xyz", ...)` use the [intrinsic concatenation convention](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler).

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
r = R.from_matrix(r0_to_r1)
euler_xyz_intrinsic_active_degrees = r.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)
euler_xyz_intrinsic_active_degrees
```

Result: `array([-148.20762964,   -3.6166255 ,    3.30106818])`

You can obtain the same result with pytransform3d (note that we obtain the passive rotation matrix by `.T`):

```py
import pytransform3d.rotations as pr
euler_xyz_intrinsic_active_radians = pr.euler_xyz_from_matrix(r0_to_r1.T)
np.rad2deg(euler_xyz_intrinsic_active_radians)
```

Result: `array([-148.20762951,   -3.61662542,    3.30106799])`

You can also obtain the rotation matrix from euler angles with pytransform3d (note that we obtain the active rotation matrix by `.T`):

```py
r0_to_r1_from_euler = pr.matrix_from_euler_xyz(euler_xyz_intrinsic_active_radians).T
r0_to_r1_from_euler
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0.99635251,  0.08212125,  0.0231898 ],
       [ 0.05746796, -0.84663889,  0.52905579],
       [ 0.06308011, -0.52579339, -0.84827013]])
```